# How can I get value of a GridView control in Eval?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView ItemTemplate column in which I have two controls .. DropDownList and a LinkButton. I want to show the selectedItem of DropDownon LinkButton. I am easily able to do so through code behind from selected index changed event. But the problem is that I am not able to maintain the state of the linkbutton when I add a new row on a button click. (because it is not bound to any datasource) 
Anyways, can I bind LinkButton with the selected Value of the Dropdown? Something like:

`Eval(drp1.SelectedItem.ToString())`

Comment: Can you add some code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

If DropDownList is databound from another table, you can add the "Text Value" of the DropDownList from database and display its value to LinkButton.
For example:

If I've a table holds countries and DropDownList to display them, and I've another table storing country Id. In your scenario you can add Inner Join to your select query and display country name in LinkButton text.